# Why isn't sound coming from my headphones in Ubuntu 14.04, but working with speakers?

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, headphones

I've had a bit of trouble with sound on my Dell XPS 13 9343 (2015) ever since I installed the GNOME 3 Desktop Environment to replace Unity. The problems I've having are:

- Plugging in headphones is laggy - the OS doesn't seem to pick up that I have headphones plugged in, until 3 - 5 seconds after the fact

  - Unplugging my speakers has the same issues; the OS doesn't seem to pick up that they're gone for a few seconds
- Sound does **not** come through any headphones plugged in the headphone jack. Attempting to do a sound test on the headphones is fruitless.

I ran a sound diagnostic through ALSA; here's the link to my results:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=c14a976b8064958b561750ffcd29282236316dfb

Can anyone help me out? I like GNOME a lot so far, and don't understand why changing desktop environments would mess up sound, yet alone only the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

On command line try

```
alsamixer
```

it will open a "gui" with several columns for each output, move with the left arrow key to the second one `<headphnes>`, and with the up arrow key, increase the volume.

It worked for me with the headphones and subwoofer.

Comment: Didn't work - my headphone volume was up at max when I started alsamixer. Headphones still didn't work. Speakers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to see
- if the headphones in alsamixer are muted. It is visualized with a M at the bottom of the volumemeter.

also on my Dell XPS 13 (Kubuntu 15.04, 4.1.2 Mainline Kernel), when the headphones are plugged in at boot time they stay mute. I **always** have to unplug and plug again for them to work.

Maybe that helps?

  -